# How to use sed to only replace first match

Tags: sed

I am trying to apply a series of `s/foo/baz/g` in sed, and I want it to stop processing a single line on the first match, do the replacement, and then move to the next line.
Basically, I will put the most specific matches at the top and only if it can't match anything else, should it fall back to the most generous pattern

Example sed file:

```
s/Execution error for request ([0-9]+). Reason: (ESS-[0-9]+) Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request ([0-9]+). Job error is/\1 \2/g
s/Execution error for request ([0-9]+). Reason: com.jbo.AttrValException: (JBO-[0-9]+): Attribute RequestId is required./1 /2/p
s/Execution error for request ([0-9]+). .*/\1/p
```

Example input:

```
Execution error for request 12345678. Reason: com.jbo.AttrValException: JBO-27035: Attribute RequestId is required.
Execution error for request 87546213. Reason: ESS-07033 Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 87546213. Job error is: null.
Execution error for request 54789632. Reason: null
```

Expected output:

```
87546213 ESS-07033
12345678 JBO-27035
54789632
```

As you can see, the expression is the most forgiving and would match all 3, but I need the other more specific ones to be tried and remapped first. The behavior I am seeing is that sed it matching, then passing to the next expression the newly morphed values, etc. So, it's becoming: `f(g(h(x)))` instead of `f(x) or g(x) or h(x)`

here is how I am running sed:
`sed -E -n -f $filter $input`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `t` command.

Fixing your script:

```
s/Execution error for request ([0-9]+). Reason: (ESS-[0-9]+) Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request ([0-9]+). Job error is.*/\1 \2/p
t
s/Execution error for request ([0-9]+). Reason: com.jbo.AttrValException: (JBO-[0-9]+): Attribute RequestId is required./\1 \2/p
t
s/Execution error for request ([0-9]+). .*/\1/p
t
```

From: [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> [2addr]**t** [*label*]
>
> Test. Branch to the **:** command verb bearing the *label* if any substitutions have been made since the most recent reading of an input line or execution of a *t*. If *label* is not specified, branch to the end of the script.